# Lowering the power of a linear differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$L(x)\equiv x^{(n)}+a_1(t)x^{(n-1)}+...+a_{n-1}x'+a_n(t)=0.$$

The solutions $x_1, x_2,...,x_m (m<n)$ are given. Linearly independent. Let us find $x_{m+1},...,x_n$

It's starts off like this, I am completely clueless as to why this is:

> $$x=x_1\int y dt$$

$$ \\ x'=x_1' \int y dt+ x_1y \\ .... \\ .... \\ \text{So we get the following:} \\$$

> $$x_1y^{n-1}+ A_1(t)y^{n-2}+ L(x_1)\int ydt=0$$

I highlighted what is unclear to me. I'll keep adding on text later if I understand this much, and once again encounter a problem going forward from there.

Comment: Can you provide the source of this problem? Also, is $x_1$ a constant, or does it depend on $t$?

Comment: It depends upon $t$...